# Has super saiyan kaioken ever been animated in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

The Dragon Ball Heroes wikia claims Xeno Vegito can use the super saiyan kaioken technique and there is this picture of it, which I dont know where it comes from.

[image]

[Super Saiyan Kaioken Dragon Ball wikia](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Kaio-ken)

Does it come from a card, or has super saiyan kaioken ever been animated in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Comment: The link in the Wikia article is to the *Dragon Ball Heroes* video game, not to the manga or anime.

Comment: @F1Krazy As far as I know, there are 3 animated segments of Dragon Ball Heroes. 1- The mini series 2- The "special/(s)" and 3- The videogame which makes animated scenes. May be you mean the japanese animation of the videogame is not "anime", but it's part of the "videogame universe". If that would be the case, I dont think what we see in the animated segments of the videogame are unrelated to the mini series completely, after all if I recall correctly, we've seen Broly being animated first in the videogame and now it's in the mini series. It seems like a kind of source material

Answer (score -1):

Dragon Ball Heroes is an independent series with its own story arcs as well as original characters. It also uses both the plot and characters from both Dragon Ball Super and GT to fuel its storyline, but it does not affect either of the series. So therefor, no. This is proven at this [Link](https://www.quora.com/Will-Dragon-Ball-Heroes-continue-after-the-Tournament-of-Power-or-will-it-be-something-totally-different).